# R Shiny Coloring a specific cell of a DataTable in each row

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny application where there is a table displayed using the DT library. I have also incorporated an option that will stratify the table off of user input (so the table will output different data given what the user has selected). 
Is there a way to find the minimum value for each row displayed in the table and assign a color to that? I want to make it more visually pleasing. The color **should only be assigned to the minimum value of the row**. I've seen ways online that allow you to color columns but in the context of my application I am comparing columns against one another, hence why I want the row minimum.

---

Lets use some sample data to help illustrate my point:

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

gg <- data.frame()
data(iris)
iris = head(iris[,-5])
#Find minimum value of the row
datatable(iris)
for (j in 1:nrow(iris)){
  gg[j,1] = j; gg[j,2] = which(iris[j,] == min(iris[j,]))
}
```

The for loop finds and stores the minimum value of row j alongside its respective column, it will be a jx2 data frame where j is the number of rows. So I would only want the minimum value of each **row** to be highlighted/colored, in this case it happens to be the last column, but it wont always be the case. I am wondering if I can use the %>% formatStyle function 'j' many times, or loop it somehow?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatstyle and change target to cell insted of row.

You can adapt this code to your problem:

```
if(result[1,1]=="some value"){
                    my_colors = ifelse(my_vals=="FALSE",'limegreen','grey88')
                }else{
                    my_colors = ifelse(my_vals=="FALSE",'tomato','grey88')
                }
                
                df%>%
                    formatStyle('DB', target = 'row',backgroundColor = styleEqual(my_vals,my_colors))
```

hope it helps.

JB